# Subtracting two timestamp arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays I created which hold a number of timestamps. The timestamps are in month,day,year,hour,sec format (eg. 12/8/2009 10:00) and I hope to use them to calculate speed. I have the speed function almost finished, I just cannot figure out how to be able to subtract the two arrays to find the difference between them. I tried using np.subtract..

```
def speedofelephant(lat1, long1, time1, lat2, long2, time2):
    distance = haversine_distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)  # meter

    delta_time = np.subtract(time1,time2)

    print delta_time

    # set speed
    speed = (distance / delta_time) # speed in m/s
    speed = speed * 3.6 # speed in km/h
```

But I get this error...

```
NotImplemented

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/script.py", line 187, in <module>
    speed=speedofelephant(lat1, long1, time1, lat2, long2, time2)
  File "C:/script.py", line 182, in speedofelephant
    speed = (distance / delta_time) # speed in m/s
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'NotImplementedType'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Just use `delta = time1 - time2` if they are in most datetime formats.

Use `dateutil.parser` to parse to `datetime.datetime` objects.

**EDIT**: Subtracting datetimes gives you a timedelta. Youll need to convert this to seconds so use `delta.totalseconds()`.

Comment: the problem is that when I use delta = time1 - time2 is that I get this error                                                                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-------", line 187, in <module>
    speed=speedofelephant(lat1, long1, time1, lat2, long2, time2)
  File "-----------", line 177, in speedofelephant
    delta_time = time1 - time2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Ah. This is because your subtracting numpy arrays. I was confused as to the data type. Are both the same length and what are their shapes? I think it should be `(n_rows_in_both, )`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty new at python, how would I their length and shape? There is an equal amount of timestamps in each array if that what you mean?

Comment: len(arr) and arr.shape

Comment: >>> len(time1)
1217
>>> len(time2)
1217
>>> time1.shape
(1217,)
>>> time2.shape
(1217,)

Comment: Alright, this will work but it isnt the pure numpy solution. `np.array([(times1[i] - times2[i]) for i in range(len(times1))]). Ill look for a better way. Im surprised subtracting the raw arrays doesnt work.

Comment: OH! I see. Subtracting the arrays does work, the issue is dividing it by a float. Convert the timedeltas to seconds with the `.totalseconds()` thing or the np equivalent then divide by the float value.

Edit: The trick is to have the deltas be a numpy array of floats rather than np.datetime objects. Then dividing by a float is straightforward

Comment: would you be willing to give me an example script?